# Simple Injector async life time scoping and security exception

Tags: c#, decorator, simple-injector, lifetime-scoping, security-critical

I have a `AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand>` and `LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand>` as shown below:

```
public class AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> 
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand {

    private readonly Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> _factory;

    public AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator(Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> factory) {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [SecurityCritical]
    // with or whitout SecurityCritical attribute, problem exists. 
    public void Handle(TCommand command) {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
            var handler = _factory();
            handler.Handle(command);
        });
    }
}

// AND

public class LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand>
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand {

    private readonly Container _container;
    private readonly Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> _factory;

    public LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator(Container container,
        Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> factory) {
        _container = container;
        _factory = factory;
    }


    [SecurityCritical]
    // with or whitout SecurityCritical attribute, problem exists. 
    public void Handle(TCommand command) {
        using (_container.BeginLifetimeScope()) {
            var handler = _factory();
            handler.Handle(command);
        }
    }
}
```

and I register decorators like this:

```
container.RegisterSingleDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator<>),
    c => c.ImplementationType.Name.StartsWith("Async"));

container.RegisterSingleDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator<>),
    c => c.ImplementationType.Name.StartsWith("Async"));
```

But, when the async process attempt to invoke, I get this error:

> Attempt by security transparent method
>   'LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator`1.Handle(!0)' to
>   access security critical method
>   'SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorLifetimeScopeExtensions.BeginLifetimeScope(SimpleInjector.Container)'
>   failed.

I tried to use `SecurityCritical` attribute on both `LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator.Handle` and `AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator.Handle`, but it didn't help. Have you any idea please?

**UPDATE:**

The exception is of type `MethodAccessException` and here is the complete stack trace:

> at MYNAMESPACE.LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator`1.Handle(TCommand
>   command)
>
> at MYNAMESPACE.AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator`1.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object
>   _)
>
> ```
>    in C:\MYPROJECTPATH\AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator.cs:line 23
> ```
>
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>
> at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

**UPDATE 2:**

With or whitout `SecurityCritical` attribute, problem exists.

Comment: Can you supply the exception type and complete stack trace.

Comment: @Steven yes, I update the Q and put the exception type and complete stack trace. Thanks to your help.

Comment: Why do you need the `[SecurityCritical]` attributes? Doesn't the problem go away without them?

Comment: @Steven Nop. I put this attribute after I got the problem. I googled the error and found some articles that they told when a security transparent method is calling a security critical one, one of ways that can resolve the problem is making the security transparent method `SecurityCritical`. With or without them, no differences.

Comment: Here is one of articles I found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264475.aspx

Comment: @Steven any result? any suggestion? I'm searching, but no result yet :( I saw the source at codeplex; But there is not `SecurityCritical` attribute on `BeginLifetimeScope`. So, why this error happens? Have you any idea?

Comment: Are you running in partial trust?

Comment: @Steven yes, I was running it in partial trust. But now, I run in full trust and problem resolved. I'm using MVC 4, .NET 4.5, Win 7, IIS Express 8, VS 2012. In full trust, there is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer (thanks to @Steven for his helps).
In my assembly, I have added **`[SecurityTransparent]`** for some reasons. In the other hand, **Simple Injector** uses the **`ThreadLocal<T>`** internally. And the **`ThreadLocal<T>`** is attributed by **`HostProtection(SecurityAction.LinkDemand)`** and in **`LinkDemand`**'s comment, we can read:

> The immediate caller is required to have been granted the ***specified permission***. **Do not use in the .NET framework 4**. For full trust use **`System.Security.SecurityCriticalAttribute`** instead; for partial trust, use **`System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand`**.

That means actually the **`ThreadLocal<T>`** class is a **`SecurityCritical`** object and we can not call a **`SecurityCritical`** method by a **`SecurityTransparent`** one.